# Is there an ancient Greek metafont font?

Tags: greek, metafont

Are there any metafont fonts that can be used to typeset classical
Greek?

Comment: See the `levy` and `lfb` folders under `/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/doc/fonts/`

Comment: Claudio Beccari’s fonts come with Metafont source.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes there are.

I recommend Claudio Beccari's version of the Greek fonts available from [CTAN in the package cbgreek-complete](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/cbgreek-complete). They are in a Didot style giving a good match with Computer Modern for the Latin alphabet.